# rails3, confused about using params[:filename].tempfile.path vs params[:filename][:tempfile].path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, temporary-files

On a Rails 3 app hosted at Heroku, where a multipart file is POSTed to my app, I'm trying to use some sample code that says :

```
File.open(params['filename'][:tempfile].path)
```

however, my logs show the error NoMethodErr no such method as tempfile.

I also tried

```
File.open(params[:filename].tempfile.path)
```

got the same error.

I added  `require 'tempfile'` to my Controller, made no difference.

Comment: can you show the view file also..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a file is posted to your application, the object in the params should already be a Tempfile so calling [:tempfile] or .tempfile should not be necessary. Try something like this:

```
File.open params[:filename].path
```

Comment: it needed ot be params['filename'].temofile.path Thank you for your suggestion, the text you wrote about tempfile being done fo rus was actually the key to debugging a problem where they used the SAME keyname 'filename' in BOTH the POSt data and the url, so the latter overwrites the former.